# How to pass redux store props via Route render using react-router?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am a redux beginner and stuck at passing redux props to route render problem.

```
×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'quantity' of undefined
PageLayout._this.render
src/components/controls/PageLayoutRoute/PageLayoutRoute.js:135
  132 |     to: routes.checkout,
  133 |     withArrow: true,
  134 |     bold: true,
> 135 |     disabled: (this.props.nonFrameDisplay.quantity == 0 && this.props.frameDisplay.quantity == 0) ? true : false
  136 |   };
  137 | }
  138 |
```

PageLayoutRoute looks like this.

```
const PageLayoutRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  return (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      <PageLayout {...props}>
        <Component />
      </PageLayout>}
  />
  )
};

PageLayoutRoute.propTypes = {
  component: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  nonFrameDisplay: state.app.nonFrameDisplay,
  frameDisplay: state.app.frameDisplay,
});
const mapDispatchToProps = {
};
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PageLayoutRoute));
```

PageLayout component is contained within PageLayoutRout. Looks like this.

```
class PageLayout extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
    hideTopNav: PropTypes.bool,
    hideBottomNav: PropTypes.bool,
    ...bottomNavProps
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    hideTopNav: false,
    hideBottomNav: false
  };
```

How can I pass nonFrameDisplay, FrameDisplay props from redux store via Route render using react-router-dom ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: where is your `reducers`

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
const PageLayoutRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  return (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      <PageLayout {...props}>
        <Component />
      </PageLayout>}
  />
  )
};
```

The props received after connecting `PageLayoutRoute` to Store are passed on to the Route component by

```
<Route
    {...rest}
```

however these are not passed onto the Component rendered by Route,

You need to do something like

```
const PageLayoutRoute = ({component: Component, nonFrameDisplay, frameDisplay, ...rest }) => {
  return (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      <PageLayout
          {...props}
          nonFrameDisplay={nonFrameDisplay}
          frameDisplay={frameDisplay}
      >
        <Component />
      </PageLayout>}
  />
  )
};

PageLayoutRoute.propTypes = {
  component: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  nonFrameDisplay: state.app.nonFrameDisplay,
  frameDisplay: state.app.frameDisplay,
});
const mapDispatchToProps = {
};
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PageLayoutRoute));
```